# I have found my email online in a .txt file. What should be my next steps?

Tags: email, gdpr, information-exposure

A few days ago someone tried to log into my bank account, the attempt was unsuccessful but it was quite concerning. I’ve spent the past weekend moving my most important accounts to alternate emails and setting up TFA everywhere. I plan to get rid of my old email altogether since it was also used to sign up for some random websites and newsletters in the past weeks.

As a part of the clean up I’ve run a Google search for my email and found a .txt file online with my email and thousands of others. They were categorised as valid/invalid. The site was since taken down but I have screenshots.

I live in the E.U. and I’ve been thinking about a GDPR or a police report. The website owner was really easy to find and lives in the same country as me.

What should be a next step?

Comment: This is not an information security question. And you are, perhaps, overreacting. Email addresses are public (it is attached to every email you send and easy to look up). And people can mistakenly use your email address to sign up for things or to even log into their own services using your email by mistake, if they are similar. There is nothing in this situation that suggests that your email account was compromised in any way. But you could check that email service's login log to see if there are any anomalies.

Comment: Then what type of question is this? 

I’m not overreacting btw. GDPR defines emails as personal data.

Comment: And one's name is covered under GDPR, too, but it is not a breach, nor is it illegal, to write someone's name down.

Comment: What type of question is this? At best, it's a legal question (how do I craft a report to the ICO about the site that hosted a user-provided file with my email address in it), but this doesn't fall under any law or the GDPR.

Comment: "I’ve spent the past weekend moving my most important accounts to alternate emails" and "I plan to get rid of my old email altogether" and "I want to file a police report" -- this is all overreaction.

Comment: That comment is not unkind. It's just not what you wanted to hear.

Comment: Look, I can create a program that scrapes public databases and even tests random account names. I can gather all working emails, and put them into a database. None of this is illegal, and nothing has "gone wrong" when this happens. And it happens constantly as a normal part of many legitimate businesses. Not to mention that your email address is attached to every email you send. So, there is nothing to "react" to in all that.

Comment: Second, nothing has "gone wrong" if someone ***attempts*** to log in to your bank account. Especially if it was unsuccessful. Anyone can try any account name on any service. So, to "burn your email address" because someone logged in is not useful, or effective. The fact that you found your email address in one specific location is meaningless. The fact that it was used in other areas might be completely unrelated. People use my email address to sign up for things all the time. And have for years. So, yes, what you have done is an overreaction.

Comment: It’s a GDPR regulation, it’s a personal email, I can be identified based on the email and I have suffered personal consequences as a result of the breach. Source: https://hnksolicitors.com/news/is-revealing-my-email-address-a-breach-of-gdpr/

Comment: Making sure that you have MFA enabled is always good advice, so it's good, in general,  that you've done that.

Comment: I'm not getting into the legal stuff (and you are interpreting the regulation incorrectly and making some assumptions). And legal stuff is off-topic here.